# Can I store the Monero local blockchain on a Ledger Nano S?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, blockchain, ledger, trezor, remote-node

So all I know about Ledger or Trezor is that you can make wallets from any cryptocurrency.
I want to import my local blockchain once and forever, instead of getting an external SSD disk (for fast synchronization), I am wondering if I could just import my local node to the Ledger Nano S device.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No.  There is only a few MB, not 100's of GB on the device for apps and key stores.